# WiFi not working when waking up computer

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

When I wake up my laptop from sleep mode, I have to reset the network card (almost) every time in order to connect to the WiFi network. This happens on different WiFi's, so the problem is with the computer / network card. I have tried re-installing the driver.

Additional info:
Asus Zenbook, Win 8, Intel 6235 network card.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you get the driver from?

Comment: Have a look in device manager click on properties on wifi card then search for enable this device to sleep